Roboflow dataset not downloading
I have tried to merge the dataset of 2 version of same project in Roboflow, by downloading the zip on birth the dataset and the adding all the data of test train and val values to other downladed dataset.
Then I created a new project and added the combined dataset to that project, and tried to download the dataset in the colab with the code of new dataset, but the dataset is not visible in the file after running the code. What should I do?


I checked all the addresses and everything seems fine.

Hi! Not sure if you managed to fix your problem, but have you tried with different dataset versions?
